# MongoDB - Connection to GUI fails after upgrading from free to M10?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, connection, studio3t

I have a problem when I want to connect to my MongoDB database (MongoAtlas). I have used Studio3T, but now I am not able to connect to my database any more. When I insert the Connection URI to 3T, I get the following response:

Connection failed.

```
SERVER [xxx.mongodb.net:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 8000: 'could not find config for xxx.mongodb.net' on server xxx.mongodb.net:27017. 
|_... 
|_... The full response is:
|_... { 

|_...     "ok" : NumberInt(0), 

|_...     "errmsg" : "could not find config for xxx.mongodb.net", 

|_...     "code" : NumberInt(8000), 

|_...     "codeName" : "AtlasError"

|_... }
```

I have also tried to connect via MongoCompass in case I copied a false URI, because it it detects the string from my clipboard. From Compass I get the following error:

```
Server at xxx.mongodb.net:27017 reports wire version 0, 
but this version of Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB2.6).
```

All of this happened after I have upgraded my cluster to M10.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution?